# Suggest a better way to make panorama video

Tags: c#, image, video

I am trying do make panorama video from PC game.
Here are the steps.

1. Save images from different angles, interval == 30ms. (The game can be paused.)
2. Stitch images for (video length/30ms) times.
3. Make panorama video from Step 2.

However, doing this will produce so many images. Is there a better way?

By the way, I was wondering, after finish Step 2, images from Step 1 can be deleted immediately. When generating Step 1 images, is it possible to save images at RAM or somewhere, but not in HDD.

Comment: Did I read that right, every _0.03ms_? That would generate something like 30.000 images in less than a second. Even if your hardware had the speed to pull this feat you would need something like 200Gb of RAM for images with FullHD resolution.

Comment: Ah-ha, my bad, it should be 30ms, thanks.